# Why did a cancelled factory recovery on my laptop leave the hard drive corrupted?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I cancelled the factory recovery process on my Toshiba Laptop L645.

It corrupted the hard drive somehow, and I can't open a file on the hard drive – so in the end I had to reformat my hard drive.

What caused this?

Comment: Please try and be a little bit clearer in your explanations. It might help using Google Translate or another service to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting factory recovery restores a system image onto the hard drive, effectively the same thing as formatting the drive in the first place. Since you cancelled it, the image was not completely copied and the partition was invalid or missing files.

Essentially, once you've started factory recovery there is no way back. You might be able to find some of your missing files if you use a data recovery program, but don't count on it.

Remember - files you don't have backed up are files you didn't really want that much in the first place.

Comment: There is one more effect, I can not run my windows, because when I turn on my laptop, there is a process like reinstalling windows ("windows is loading  files") after that there is such a frame informing me that the recovery has failed and when I click 'ok' the system will reboot and continue to repeat again and again.

Comment: @TOFIK you need to start the Toshiba recovery all over again, from the beginning. Consult the Toshiba website to see how to start it from the bios/hard drive, or use the Toshiba Recovery discs.